# Aggregate function at Subquery And Performance Issue

Tags: sql, function, subquery, aggregate

I have query which i should select records from 1 table to insert another table once everyday(Select  Into). It's big and enough complicated query for me because of i want to do it it 1 query. Here is piece of query which i want to change(it has many inner join and group by variables) :

```
Select  RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) 
THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),(Select Cast([Start] as time) 
as Start FROM [dbo].[Period] Where strDay=DATEPART(dw,CAST('2017-01-30' as date)) 
And Timezone=[dbo].[Timezone].Timezone))/60),2) +':'+ 
RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) 
THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),(Select Cast([Start] as time) as Start 
FROM [dbo].[Period] Where strDay=DATEPART(dw,CAST('2017-01-30' as date)) 
And Timezone=[Timezone].Timezone))%60),2) AS WorkingHours from  [dbo].[Events]
```

This query works and it give returns such answer 01:25 hours. When i want to change [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) to [EnteranceDevice] IN(Select ReaderInput from [SPS].[dbo].Users) it gives "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery" error

1. How can i solve this problem?
2. ReaderInput(nvarchar(50)) has such values(at 1 record) '1,3,5' because of it should store more than 1 device ID but EnteranceDevice is int. So Casting(`Cast(EnteranceDevice as nvarchar(50)) IN(...)`  ) will work?
3. I'm sure that you see many performance issues at my code. I want to hear recommendations about query.

Answer (score 0):

remember... saying something is "in" is the same same as saying left join and target is not null, so the refactoring is easy as follows:

could not read your code had to reformat it to have some sort of logic....

```
Select  
  RIGHT(
    '0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),
    (Select Cast([Start] as time) as Start FROM [dbo].[Period] Where strDay=DATEPART(dw,CAST('2017-01-30' as date)) And Timezone=[dbo].[Timezone].Timezone))/60),
    2
  ) +
  ':'+ 
  RIGHT(
    '0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),
    (Select Cast([Start] as time) as Start FROM [dbo].[Period] Where strDay=DATEPART(dw,CAST('2017-01-30' as date)) And Timezone=[Timezone].Timezone))%60),
  2) AS WorkingHours 
from  [dbo].[Events]
```

First of all you have the same sub-query twice.  Pull that out into a cross join

```
Select  
  RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),x.start)/60),2) +
  ':'+ 
  RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] IN(1) THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),x.start)%60),2) AS WorkingHours 
from  [dbo].[Events]
cross join (
  Select Cast([Start] as time) as Start 
  FROM [dbo].[Period] 
  Where strDay=DATEPART(dw,CAST('2017-01-30' as date)) 
    And Timezone=[Timezone].Timezone
) x
```

Now join to users and check for null

```
Select  
  RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN u.ReaderInput is not null THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),x.start)/60),2) +
  ':'+ 
  RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(CASE WHEN u.ReaderInput is not null THEN CAST(EventDate as datetime) ELSE NULL END),x.start)%60),2) AS WorkingHours 
from  [dbo].[Events]
left join [SPS].[dbo].Users u on [EnteranceDevice] = u.ReaderInput
cross join (
  Select Cast([Start] as time) as Start 
  FROM [dbo].[Period] 
  Where strDay=DATEPART(dw,CAST('2017-01-30' as date)) 
    And Timezone=[Timezone].Timezone
) x
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I will correct my all twice sub-queries. And
there is something about [EnteranceDevice] and [ReaderInput]. [EnteranceDevice] is int and it gets integer numbers such 1,2,4,6 etc. And [ReaderInput] is nvarchar(50) and it can have vales as '2,3,5' or just '4'. So CASE WHEN [EnteranceDevice] iS NOT NULL will enough? Because of EnteranceDevice value should be in ReaderInput column.

Comment: not sure probably if `[EnteranceDevice] = u.ReaderInput` is not comparing the same types then one side would have to change to cast to the other type.  This is not very common -- they should be the same type or something is very wrong with your design.